# Prioritizing and routing inbound traffic to virtual interfaces based on port with PF_RING

Tags: networking, routes, pf-ring

I have a system connected to a SPAN port which pumps out a near-constant 10Gbps of raw network traffic. My main objective is to observe all DHCP traffic with zero loss, but I also need to be able to observe the (acceptably lossy) stream of non-DHCP traffic. The native interface is currently dropping about %0.25 of all traffic as-is.

To get this working I'm envisioning the following:

- Inbound SPAN traffic comes in on a single interface which prioritizes DHCP above all else
- Traffic is routed to two virtual interfaces based on if it is DHCP (port 67/68) or not

The code that I'm using to process/analyze the traffic can be run in parallel, and each instance can watch a different interface. The biggest unknown for me is that it uses PF_RING. I am not overly familiar with PF_RING, and have not been able to tell if it is preventing the `tc`-based filtering from working as I expect.

I've attempted to get this working via `tc`, but am struggling to get it to work as expected. I used the following sequence of commands, where `br0` is the original input interface:

```
ip link add dummy0 type dummy
ip link set dummy0 up

# Create the ingress queue discipline
tc qdisc add dev br0 handle ffff: ingress

# Setup the filters to mirror UDP traffic to dummy0
tc filter add dev br0 parent ffff: protocol ip u32 match ip dport 67 0x00ff action mirred egress redirect dev dummy0
tc filter add dev br0 parent ffff: protocol ip u32 match ip dport 68 0x00ff action mirred egress redirect dev dummy0
tc filter add dev br0 parent ffff: protocol ip u32 match ip sport 67 0x00ff action mirred egress redirect dev dummy0
tc filter add dev br0 parent ffff: protocol ip u32 match ip sport 68 0x00ff action mirred egress redirect dev dummy0
```

This seems to get DHCP traffic mirrored to a virtual interface (`dummy0`) on a test VM which is not running PF_RING, but when I try the same on my full system it produces erratic results (I get non-DHCP things on the `dummy0` interface, and it looks like I'm missing DHCP traffic as well). I also have not been able to get DHCP-based prioritization working on the input interface, which I think is just my lack of understanding of the `tc PRIO` commandset.

Comment: Unfortunately, your problem is going to be on the other side of the SPAN interface. Switches really do not have much buffer, and they simply tail-drop excess traffic. The hardware buffer on the interface is first in, first out, and you will certainly lose frames with DNS packets in the same way that you will lose other frames, all happening before the frames are sent to your host for reception. Assume your switch has 48 1 Gbps interfaces for traffic, and one 10 Gbps SPAN interface, if the other interfaces are operating at 100%, your switch will drop about 80% of traffic to the SPAN interface.

Comment: Thanks @RonMaupin, that makes sense. Given that I cannot do much to change that side of the system, though, do you have any suggestions for how to prioritize inbound DHCP and re-route it to a virtual interface on my side of the connection? I can always lean on the maintainers of the other side to improve their setup, but it is much easier to make that request if I can say that I am doing everything possible on my side to ensure minimal loss of DHCP.